# Unable to get the List<Integer> output to Katalon Test case

Tags: java, katalon-studio

I have been working to get the list of Arraylist output to Testcase

Here is my code(Keyword):

```
@Keyword
public List<Integer> othersites() {

        String[] sits = new String[9];

        sits[0] = "https://www.tadawul.com.sa/wps/portal/tadawul/home/";
        sits[1] = "https://www.msm.gov.om/";


        WebUI.navigateToUrl(sits[0]);
        String tdwl = WebUI.getText(findTestObject('Object Repository/Sites/site_tdwl'),FailureHandling.CONTINUE_ON_FAILURE)
        String[] parts0 = tdwl.split("\\.")
        String part0 = parts0[0];
        String part00 = Integer.parseInt(part0.replaceAll(",", ""))
        //println part00


        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add(part00);


        List<Integer> newList1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(list.size()) ;

        for (String myInt1 : list)
        {
            newList1.add(Integer.valueOf(myInt1));
        }

        return newList1

    }
```

Katalon Test case:

```
def newList1 = [];

newList1 << CustomKeywords.'decypha_equities.otherSiteValuesCapture.othersites'();
println newList1[0];
```

I could get the whole Arraylist, but i need to access to array elements in my test case(not inside the keyword)?

my output:

```
[8056, 3997, 6547, 10295, 2890, 14908, 1551, 1801, 5114]
```

Comment: Please explain what does "sitting on my test case" mean. What are the results of your code? Any error messages? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: **what i need is access to array element one by one** ,  since printing array is a list object ,it printing as one of the element in full array. updated the Question accordingly and no error message(but not the output which i am expecting)

Comment: lets say what i need is some thing like this int[0] = 8056 , int[1] = 3997 ...  but when i do so  it is printing whole new array

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`othersites()` method is returning the whole list. And then you are assigning the result to a new list with `newList1 << CustomKeywords.'decypha_equities.otherSiteValuesCapture.othersites'();`.

Change your test case to this

```
def newestList = CustomKeywords.'decypha_equities.otherSiteValuesCapture.othersites'();
println newestList[0];
```

to access the first element of the list.